# Minimum of $\max(1-2x+y,1+2x+y,x^2-y^2)$ for $x,y(y\ge 0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

We define $$S(x,y)=\max(1-2x+y, \, 1+2x+y, \, x^2-y^2)$$
on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

How do we find the minimum value of $S(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\max(1-2x+y, \, 1+2x+y)=1+2|x|+y$ you can rewrite this as

$$S(x,y)= \max(1+2|x|+y, \, x^2-y^2)$$

For $y \ge 0$,  $S(x,y) \ge 1+2|x|+y \ge 1$ and $S(0,0)=1$ so the minimum is $1$

Answer (score 3):

One of $1-2x+y,1+2x+y$ should $\geq1$. So $S\geq1$. On the other hand, consider $x=0,y=0$, the minimal value is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $S(x,y)=S(-x,y)$, so find $$\min_{x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}}\max(1+2x+y,x^2-y^2)$$
and find the cutoff line where $1+2x+y=x^2-y^2$.